# How do I lay a grid and count the number of points within each sector?

Tags: qgis-3, vector-grid

[image]I'm using QGIS and this represents a metro area that is 3,965 square miles.  I want to lay a grid over it and measure the number of points in each sector.  I haven't used any of the grid tools before and there are a lot to choose from.  What tool would be used to lay over this map and count the number of values?  Will the grid automatically count the number of values within it or do I need to run a separate tool? [image]

Comment: @MrXsquared: I guess this is already an (the) answer :-)

Comment: But there is only one polygon, in green.  The grid is just a virtual layer, right?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify.  The green shape is one large polygon.  I want to create a grid where each grid square is something like 100 square meters and see how many points fall within each grid square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open your [processing toolbar](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/de/docs/user_manual/processing/toolbox.html) and search for "Create Grid".

[image]

Which will return something like this:

[image]

Then run "Count Points in Polygon" from processing toolbar and set your layers:

[image]

Which will return a copy of your grid layer including the number of points inside:

[image]

Comment: I just tried this but NUMPOINTS comes up as zero for every entry.  I added a new screenshot, and it seems like there are points within each grid square, so I'm not sure why they don't register.

Comment: Hm, they should be counted. Cant really tell remotely. Maybe check your settings and try again.

Comment: I messed with the settings and still the same results.  It's a 100m x 100m grid.  I will make this as a new question to post if that's okay.